# Unable to convert Protobuf to map becasue of 'Direct self-reference leading to cycle' error

Tags: protocol-buffers, self-reference, objectmapper

I am trying to convert a ProtoBuf to Map by using the below mentioned code.

Map map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);

Sample PB data causing this:
id: "1"
metadata {
  type: "UNIT"
  isValidated: false
  status {
    status: ACTIVE
  }
}

I am getting the error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.sample.samplePB["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a protobuf to JSON using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588778/convert-a-protobuf-to-json-using-jackson)