# Convert a protobuf to JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, protocol-buffers

I get the following error while converting a protobuf to JSON using Jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
MyObjectPb$MyObject["unknownFields"]->
com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["defaultInstanceForType"])
```

MyObjectPb has the following field:

```
protected com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet unknownFields
```

As I am working on an existing codebase, I have the following constraints:

1. I can't modify the source code for MyObjectPb, so I can't use Jackson's ignore annotations in MyObjectPb.
2. Neither can I use Gson's libraries to convert the object, as the codebase already uses Jackson for serialization. Adding a new dependency is not recommended.

How do I tell Jackson to ignore (de)serializing the UnknownFieldSet object inside MyObjectPb?

---

I have tried the following, but these approaches do not seem to solve the problem:

a) Configuring the ObjectMapper:

```
myObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
myObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

b) Using a Jackson Mixin:

```
@JsonIgnoreType
private abstract class UnknownFieldSetIgnoreMixIn {}

myObjectMapper.addMixIn(UnknownFieldSet.class, UnknownFieldSetIgnoreMixIn.class)
```

Comment: The mixin would have been my first guess. You may have to declare a parallel class for JSON use. MapStruct could help with conversion back and forth there.

Comment: @chrylis may I please know if the mixin implementation was suitable or am I missing something? 
I will look up MapStruct, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the JsonFormat class (com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat) to convert the protobuf:

```
new JsonFormat().printToString(myObject)
```

This did the job perfectly for me.

Comment: I think printToString does not exist anymore

Answer (score 21):

The current way (Oct-2018) to serialize a protobuf is to use `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat` in the following manner:

```
JsonFormat.printer().print(myMessageOrBuilder)
```

I used the `@JsonSerialize(using = MyMessageSerializer.class)` annotation right before my protobuf object and added this class:

```
public static class MyMessageSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Message> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Message message, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRawValue(JsonFormat.printer().print(message));
    }
}
```

This allowed  `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(wrapperObject)` to properly convert my protobuf to JSON.

Comment: gen.writeRawValue if the protobuf object is just a member in POJO class

Comment: In sprinboot webflux, this serializing option/annotaiton works. Only problem, after each proto object regeneration, we have to edit the generated java code.

Comment: I tried this but the following Exception raises: ```No serializer found for class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: ru.vtb.mmba.account.AccountProto$BankAccountInfo["unknownFields"]```

Comment: It seems that annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = ProtobufSerializer.class)` not used. If just pass `JsonFormat.printer().print(accountInfo)` to `objectMapper.writeValueAsString` then it works. So why `@JsonSerialize(using` ignored by`objectMapper.writeValueAsString`?

Comment: just out of curiosity how do you make a ProtoBuf message encapsulate as a object? because I get an output of protobuf something like `value: xyz\n` and I expected
`{"value": "xyz"}` so I'm missing the object encapsulation

Comment: I don't understand where you put the `@JsonSerialize(using = MyMessageSerializer.class)`.

Answer (score 4):

The include has changed from `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat`
to
`com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat`

So, if your protobuf dependency is missing the `format` package, try looking for `JsonFormat` in `util`.

With this include, you should be able to use

```
new JsonFormat().printToString(myObject)
```

as @amad-person suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the following class from the package `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat` as:

```
JsonFormat.printer().print()
```

Answer (score 2):

I just have this issue and use the code below for creating JSON from the Message object:

```
JsonFormat.printer().print(getMessageCockroachDB)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a protobuf library for jackson here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary

Though documentation on how to use it is sparse! There are some examples on how to use this for reading / writing: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/blob/2.14/protobuf/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/protobuf/ReadSimpleTest.java#L66

However it's not clear how this would sit within a GRPC applciation.

Answer (score 1):

I think this Jackson module handles serialization of Protobuf-generated value classes into JSON (or other Jackson-supported dataformats):

https://github.com/HubSpot/jackson-datatype-protobuf

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses [@JsonComponent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html) :

```
@JsonComponent
public class MessageSerializer  extends JsonSerializer<Message> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Message value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRawValue(JsonFormat.printer().print(value));
    }
}
```

This also regsiters the serializer with ObjectMapper for Message.class.